# Segmentation fault on pointer to pointer assignment

Tags: c, pointers, tree, malloc

I am implementing huffman compression and I am building a hufftree from a link list containing nodes. I am getting a segmentation fault on a pointer to pointer to assignment after multiple iterations. Based on my experience and research I believe the segmentation fault is due to an error present other than where the program breaks. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

P.S - I am new to stack overflow and never asked a question before so please let me know if you need more info to help me on this problem or anything else.

```
struct LinkList{
    int weight;
    struct TreeNode * bottom;
    struct LinkList * next;
}; typedef struct LinkList LinkList;

//This function takes in a link list where each node points to the next
 //element in the link list and a huff tree node. It also contains weight 
//which is equal to the weight of the hufftree that it points to.

TreeNode * huffTree(LinkList * head)
{
    LinkList * temphead = head;
    LinkList * ptr;
    LinkList * ptr1;
    int count = 127,i;
    while(count>2)
    {
        temphead = head->next->next;
        head->next->next = NULL;
        head = mergeTree(head);
        ptr = temphead;
        ptr1 = temphead;// This is where I get the segmentation fault
//when the value of count is 14
        while(head->weight>temphead->weight)
        {
            ptr1 = temphead;
            temphead = temphead->next;
        }

        if(ptr1!=temphead)
        {
            head->next = temphead;
            ptr1->next = head;
            head = ptr;
        }

        else
        {
            head->next = temphead;
        }

        count--;
    }

    head = mergeTree(head);

    TreeNode * root;
    root = head->bottom;
    head->bottom = NULL;
    free(head);
    return root;
}

LinkList * mergeTree(LinkList * head)
{
    TreeNode * tree1 = head->bottom;
    TreeNode * tree2 = head->next->bottom;
    head->bottom = NULL;
    head->next->bottom = NULL;

    free(head->next);
    free(head);

    TreeNode * newnode = (TreeNode *) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));

    newnode->weight = tree1->weight + tree2->weight;
    newnode->c = '~';
    newnode->left = tree1;
    newnode->right = tree2;

    LinkList * ptr = (LinkList *) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    ptr->weight = newnode->weight;
    ptr->bottom = newnode;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? It looks like C.

Comment: @PCLuddite - yes it is c code

Comment: @jakshay_desai Then you should remove the C++ tag.

Comment: @PCLuddite Sorry my bad! removed it

Comment: Could `temphead` (`head->next->next`) be null?  The while loop is the first access, and loading temphead->weight could easily look like the previous line in the debugger, particularly with any sort of optimization.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That shouldn't happen since the loop runs for count>2 which means at all times there are more than two nodes in the tree and therefore there exists head->next->next. if head->next->next ==NULL then count==2 then loop doesn't execute and the code will merge the remaining two trees

Answer (score 0):

My guess is on statement "while(head->weight>temphead->weight) {}". 
You have not checked if the head has become NULL when you have traversed the list.

Comment: I printed out the list right before I get a seg fault and it wasn't empty and therefore head wasn't empty. To avoid the situation you just described I have while(count>2) to start with. The program gives me a seg fault when count = 14. So everything works fine except for the fact that I am making some error else where in my program which doesn't affect the code until count drops to 14.

Answer (score 0):

In your "huffTree()" function, outer while loop (while (count > 2)) runs for 127 iterations since count is initialized with 129.

So, when huffTree() is called by caller, the input list (LinkList *head) must have 129 nodes available.

If, anyhow, the list is having lesser than 129 nodes then following NULL condition handling should be added.

```
temphead = head->next->next;
if (NULL == temphead)
{
    /* NULL condition handling */
}
```

When temphead == NULL, then temphead->weight derefrencing will result in segmentation fault in following code line

```
while(head->weight>temphead->weight)
```

head->weight is fine if malloc() is assured not to fail in mergeTree() function.

Comment: Exactly! What you suggested totally makes sense however the testcase that this function is failing on sends in a list of 129 nodes(each ascii character occupies one node). I printed out the list and temphead right before it seg faults on the assignment ptr1= temphead; Both were not NULL. Now using logic I know ptr1=temphead is not the problem if temphead!=NULL. The problem exist somewhere else in the code like you suggested (it might in mergetree) but I can't figure out what exactly that is or possible techniques to use to debug